# How to place jQuery Datepicker results on different div or span element

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I need to know how to place the results of the datepicker on to another div element. For example when a user selects a date, they should be able to preview the selected date on a different div element. This is what I have so far. I want to get the date from the input to show on the #preview_date div when the user selects the date. I know theres a way to place it on a different input element, but I do not want to place it on another input element, i want to place the results inside a DIV or SPAN.. Please help

```
<div id="preview_date"></div>

<label>Date:</label>
<input type="text" id="date" class="datepicker"/>

$(".datepicker").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        dateFormat:"DD, d MM, yy"
    });
```

Comment: You have an unclosed string on the buttonImage line, that could be part of your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the datepicker's [onSelect](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) event:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif ",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy ",
    onSelect: function (d) {
        $('#preview_date').text(d);
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/52MRm/)**